# Getting Different Average in MS-SQL Server 2014 v Excel and R

Tags: sql-server, r, excel

I am working with a data set and need to get averages. Right now I am doing a very simply calculation of Average Days Stay.

I use this in SQL:

```
ROUND(AVG(CAST(A.Performance AS float)), 3) AS [elos]
```

and get 7.467

When I take the raw data and use `summary` in `R` I get 7.136 and when I use `=AVERAGE()` in Excel I get 7.136, so my question is, what are some considerations when using `AVG()` in `SQL`? I am not sure why I am getting a different answer from SQL Server vs (R & Excel)

** UPDATE **

The variable `Performance` is of type `float` this is a straight `avg()` calculation with no grouping

Comment: What datatype is `Performance` before casting to a `float`? Perhaps you can use `decimal`/`numeric` instead?

Comment: maybe you have groupings and/or filters that are not comparing apples to apples.

Comment: @StevenHibble I'll try that - performance is float - I get the same thing when cast to numeric and decimal

Comment: @ScottCraner there is no grouping just a straight `avg()` calculation

Comment: If `Performance` is a float, why are you doing an explicit `CAST` to a float?

Comment: What precision is the float set at in the source SQL table?

Comment: @StevenHibble because I didn't realize it was a float I didn't even think to look. Regardless even without the explicit `cast()` I still get 7.467

Comment: @QHarr no precision set just set to type `float`

Comment: Try: `CAST(A.Performance AS DECIMAL(10, 4))` (don't know if (10, 4) is right for you, but it seems that should cover everything.

Comment: I just found that I needed to add a grouping, wow, not caffineted enough today

Comment: @ScottCraner you were right, I was missing a grouping in order to get distinct records...

Comment: @MCP_infiltrator ... if you had produced your entire query not just a line snippet we could have told you that.

Comment: @Parfait that was the sum of my query I was missing a grouping which would not have been caught unless I posted my data.